# Replace none value with values in the same list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi i'm new to python and i'm strugglin with this example.. I want to replace empty elements with the dates in list. For example every empty element replaced by monday until tuesday ... I'm using python 2.7.

this the list that i get :

```
[u'Monday 30 March', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'Tuesday 31 March', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'Wednesday  1 April', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
```

this is what i tried :

```
for tim in time_d:
    if tim =='':
        print time_d[0]
```

Comment: If you are new to Python, consider practicing with Python 3.x. Python 2 [is no longer supported](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: You try to print it. What if you do something else?

Comment: i want empty field in list to be replaced by the date in list for exemple i want monday to be repeted until tuesday and tuesday until wednesday and wednesday until the end of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for sth. like the following:

```
for i, val in enumerate(time_d):
    if not val:
        time_d[i] = time_d[i-1]

time_d
# ['Monday 30 March', 'Monday 30 March', ... ,'Monday 30 March', 
#  'Tuesday 31 March', 'Tuesday 31 March', ... , 'Tuesday 31 March', 
#  'Wednesday  1 April', 'Wednesday  1 April', ..., 'Wednesday  1 April']
```

This requires the first value to be set, otherwise you'd have to handle the `IndexError`.

Comment: it's near what i want but i got some extra dates for exemple in the web sites they are only 17 shows in thuesday and in the output i got 18

Comment: i found that it add an extra day in every dates is there is a way to remove 1 date of each days ?

Comment: Here's a python3.8 answer if anyone's interested `[text:=i if i else text for i in my_list]` assuming first value is always set.

Comment: When the first value is not set `text='';[text:=i if i else text for i in my_list]`

Comment: @Ch3steR That's cute =) `[t := v if v or not i else t for i, v in enumerate(my_list)]`

Comment: is there is a way to remove 1 element of each one ?

Comment: @schwobaseggl That was sneaky as hell `if v or not i`   I would have never thought of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a straightforward solution (in Python 3):

```
dates = ['Monday 30 March', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Tuesday 31 March', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Wednesday  1 April', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']     
newdates = []
current = ''
for item in dates:
    if not item:
        newdates.append(current)
    else:
        current = item
        newdates.append(current)
print(dates)
print(newdates)
```

with output:

```
['Monday 30 March', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Tuesday 31 March', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Wednesday  1 April', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['Monday 30 March', 'Monday 30 March', 'Monday 30 March', 'Monday 30 March', 'Monday 30 March', 'Monday 30 March', 'Monday 30 March', 'Monday 30 March', 'Monday 30 March', 'Monday 30 March', 'Tuesday 31 March', 'Tuesday 31 March', 'Tuesday 31 March', 'Tuesday 31 March', 'Tuesday 31 March', 'Tuesday 31 March', 'Tuesday 31 March', 'Tuesday 31 March', 'Tuesday 31 March', 'Tuesday 31 March', 'Tuesday 31 March', 'Tuesday 31 March', 'Tuesday 31 March', 'Tuesday 31 March', 'Tuesday 31 March', 'Tuesday 31 March', 'Tuesday 31 March', 'Tuesday 31 March', 'Wednesday  1 April', 'Wednesday  1 April', 'Wednesday  1 April', 'Wednesday  1 April', 'Wednesday  1 April', 'Wednesday  1 April', 'Wednesday  1 April', 'Wednesday  1 April', 'Wednesday  1 April', 'Wednesday  1 April', 'Wednesday  1 April', 'Wednesday  1 April', 'Wednesday  1 April', 'Wednesday  1 April', 'Wednesday  1 April']
```

Comment: i got the same result as schwobaseggl answer i got some extra dates in the site there is only 17 shows and in the output i got 18 on tuesday